# Нужно ли ставить запятую в предложении "Узнать, как и где провести семейный досуг?"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятую в предложении: "Узнать, как и где провести семейный досуг?"

Answer (score 2):

Да, нужна.

Вопрос "Грамоты" № 288958:

> Здравствуйте! Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в предложении: "Узнать как
>   получить книгу", каким правилом в данном случае руководствоваться?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Запятая нужна. Здесь действует правило о знаках препинания в
>   сложноподчиненном предложении. Подробнее эта ситуация описана в
>   справочниках Д. Э. Розенталя:
>
> В составе сложноподчиненного предложения может быть неполное
>   предложение — в главной части или придаточной: 1) неполное в главной
>   части: Вот уже два года, как мы женаты...; 2) неполное или близкое к
>   неполному в придаточной части: ...Делайте всё, что нужно; Поставьте,
>   как вам удобно;

Answer (score 2):

Это сложное предложение, состоящее из двух простых безличных предложений. Запятая нужна.